# SQL Server 2005 onwards- Capturing Baseline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to design a process by which I can capture the baseline data of multiple SQL Server instances (2005 onwards) in a single database from where I can get all the info and alerts.

As of now I want to capture info about the below counters:

1. Free space available on disks
2. Database File and Log space available
3. Wait statistics
4. CPU and memory counters

Is there any free tool that I can refer to and modify if needed or any useful article that can help me to set this up?

As of now I am referring to the article by Erin Stellato in SQLServerCentral.com.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Check out Rodney Landrum's SQL Server Tacklebox. It's a free book from Red Gate that includes scripts to do that:

http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/sql-server-tacklebox

Comment: Thanks alot Brent...will definitely come back to you in case I have any problem understand...thanks alot again..really appreciate..

Answer (score 3):

What Brent suggested is a great resource.

There are many way of capturing baseline for your servers, just make sure that you are not collecting too much or too less and be consistent along with having a purge job to remove old data or have some mechanism to archive the collected data.

I would suggest you to also have a look at

- [DMVstats - A SQL 2005 Performance Data Warehouse](http://sqldmvstats.codeplex.com/) on codeplex
- [Creating a baseline for SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/sql-server-baseline-creation)